# removing data from one scope, it is reflecting on another scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I made two scope: `$scope.product_remaining`, `$scope.all_products`

```
$scope.product_remaining = {};
$scope.all_products = {};

httpService.get(products_url, "")
  .then(function(result) {
      if (result.status == 200) {

        $scope.all_product = result.data;
        $scope.product_remaining = result.data;
      }
    }
```

When I remove any key from `$scope.product_remaining`, it also reflects in `$scope.all_product`.

Is it possible for that to happen? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Question un-clear. Both `product_remaining` and `all_products` are set to `result.data` so anything removed from `result.data` will not show up in both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's becuase your are assinging Like this

```
$scope.all_product = result.data;
$scope.product_remaining = result.data;
```

**`function`**,**`array`**,**`object`**,**`date`** will keep reference during assinging.

Try like this

```
$scope.all_product = angular.copy(result.data);
$scope.product_remaining = angular.copy(result.data);
```